# Excel Solver - Use even number as constraint

Tags: excel, excel-formula, solver

I would like a constraint for a formula so it can only return an `even` number.

For example:

A formula in cell `A1, *SUM(A2+A3)/2*` should only return a `even` number.

Comment: Can you show us sample data?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/6b075c4e47e0ddfc18e06f3718814ddc

The cells C15-18 I want them to be even

Comment: The column and row headers are not visible here.  This is a bad screen capture.

Comment: Please update your question to show how you want to take your data and output even numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `MOD` function:

In another cell, say `A2` have the formula `=MOD(A1,2)` and constrain it to be 0.

Another possibility is to create a new changing cell (say `B1`) and constrain it to be an integer, and then add a constraint that forces `A1 = 2*B1`. The new changing cell will have no other role to play in the model.

Comment: Your first solution was smart but dosent seem to work when I run solver, got error that no solution to match the criteria was found.

My need has changed slightly, but is still relevant to the thread title. I would like to have the "changing variable cells" only be even numbers. Hope you understand. Thanks!

Comment: `Mod` isn't continuous so that might be an issue. The second way should work. A slight modification: why not have your decision variables be 1/2 of the variables which you want to be even and replace all occurrences of the old variables in your formulas by 2 times the new variables?

Comment: Hmm not sure I understand. My variable cells are empty. Also after changing a constraint I got your Mod solution to work, thanks. But I still would like to have my variable cells to only be even numbers.

Comment: There is no way to do that directly. What you are *currently* calling your variable cells -- make them formula cells with formulas of the form `=2*x` -- where the `x` are *new* variable cells. Constrain these new cells to be integers -- which is supported directly in the solver.

Comment: I get this message when I try to add a constraint to the cells with the formula "Integer constraint cell reference must include only Variable Cells." Maybe I can use your MOD solution on my variable cells, trying that.

Comment: When I add the constraint of even numbers using `MOD` I keep getting errors, no solutions found. But I can manually find possible solutions.

Comment: My last comment should work -- add new cells, constrain these new cells and only these new cells to be integers. Take your old variable cells and replace them by formulas of the form `=2*new cell`

Comment: I think John Coleman is on the right track here. Write your model as you normally would. Restrict the variables you want to be even, to be integer. Now in every formula they are referenced, multiply them by 2 (so translate 10*even1+15*even2 as 20*int1+30*int2). So when Solver tells you the solution is int1=3, you know it is really even1=6.